# Couldn't convert date string from server to Date type using dateformatter

Tags: swift, date, timestamp, dateformatter

I have tried many questions from stack overflow, but couldn't find a proper solution.

I have tried the below code, but it returns nil

```
let datestring = "2021-04-23T00:00:00.000000Z" // date from server
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
let date = formatter.date(from: datestring) // getting nil here
```

Comment: formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Comment: @ElTomato No. The correct format is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXXX"`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. I have seen your answer ,it resolved my problem. I didn't knew about iso 8601 before, that is why your original answer came up on my google search.